# x590cafile default location for gnutls-cli

Tags: cygwin, certificate, openssl

I am using gnutls-cli from Cygwin, on a laptop running Windows XP Home (I have openssl from cygwin also).  I am wondering where does gnutls-cli look for CA certificates if I don't specify option --x509cafile?  I haven't found the answer anywhere.  I can point to my CA certificate bundle at /usr/ssl/certs & successfully verify certificates (e.g. those from AT&T Yahoo email for inbound.att.net), but I'm still wondering where does gnutls-cli look if I don't specify where to look?

Answer (score 0):

It *should* use `/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` (from the `ca-certificates` package), but it seems the Cygwin `gnutls` package is not configured to use a CA certificate bundle by default.    I just raised this with the Cygwin `gnutls` maintainer; hopefully this will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: This is fixed as of the `3.2.0-4` release.